# php can't see local mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, aptana

I'm just getting started trying to set up a server/website and have run into what is probably a very basic issue.  I'm getting a blank screen when I try to connect to my installed mysql server with a php script; e.g.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://protovis-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/protovis-r3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php 
echo "Connecting..."
$user="root";
$password="passwd";
$server="127.0.0.1";
mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
echo "Connected.";

?>
</body></html>
```

shows "Connecting..." but never reaches "Connected".  There's nothing wrong with the code or database, since this did work within the browser in Aptana 2.05 (since uninstalled).  It doesn't work within Firefox or Chrome.  Aptana was using a different (older) version of PHP, 5.2; phpinfo() accessed from Chrome/Firefox was 5.3.  The php.ini file contains extension=mysql.so; otherwise I couldn't tell if the settings were correct or not.  The tutorials I looked at didn't really cover this sort of thing... anybody know what to do?

Comment: mysql_connect returns false on failure, so if you do this: "$cn = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);" you can check the value of $cn to see if the connection is actually being made.

Comment: are you running it on port 3306? you need to specify the port on the server "server:port" if it's not the default port

Comment: @jlmcdonald No, it crashes right on the mysql_connect call--doing as you suggested still didn't produce anything, the interpreter never reaches the echo/print statement.

Comment: @Jason Thanks I hadn't tried that, but localhost:3306 (and *:80. *:8000) didn't work either.  Nor did 127.0.0.1*.

Comment: Try adding this at the start of the PHP block: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: @icktoofay Thanks! That gave me Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/test/test_sql.php on line 21.  I'll be looking this up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha!  Just didn't have the php5-mysql package installed.  So evidently having php and mysql by themselves is not enough.  Installed php5-mysql, the connection worked.

Answer (score 1):

What browser you're using has nothing to do with whether the php script running on the server connects to a database or not.

I would suggest checking the server logs, or adding some code to actually check and see what's going on:

```
$link = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but as I indicated the interpreter crashes before any reporting of the error state is possible on the basis of within-script diagnostics.  The server log doesn't show any transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL instance may be configured to not respond to localhost.  There are two ways of connecting to a MySQL server; through a network connection (ip and port) or socket connection, which only works on the machine it's working on.  Your MySQL server may be configured to listen to socket connections but not network.

1. Try connecting using the mysql command line tool as "mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -ppassword mysql"
2. Try running your PHP script from the command line instead of inside the browser.